# How serious is the Engine System Service Required message on a Volvo V50 2007?

Tags: cel, volvo

I got a 2007 Volvo V50 last week and the "Engine System Service Required" message has appeared. how serious is that message and can only a Volvo garage do the diagnostics? It has done 41000 miles. I have only driven it to work, around 180 miles over the last week.

The warranty from the seller (not a Volvo dealer) says "engine & gearbox breakdown warranty only", should this issue be covered within this kind of warranty?

The model is a V50 D5 SE Sport 5door Geartronic (diesel).

Reading with an ODB2 reader shows no fault codes logged, pending or historic. Using the Volvo inbuilt display (good READ and tap rear fog light twice) shows the following:

```
DTCS IN VEHICLE

BCM DTS SET
TCM CHECKING
ECM DTC SET
SWM CHECKING
EPS DTC SET
CEM DTC SET
SRS READY
CCM NOT CHECKED
DDM CHECKING
DIM READY
ICM NOT CHECKED
PDM DTC SET
PSM DTC SET
PAM READY
```

I presume the generic OBD2 device isn't reading the codes, so I'd need to find a mechanic with a VADIS to get the real codes?

Comment: You need to get the OBDII engine codes read, which can be done by any shop or even some auto parts stores. Without the codes, it's really hard to tell you.

Comment: I've added a few details from the inbuilt display, but it doesn't say much. I'll find out if my regular mechanic has a VADIS on Monday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Engine System Service Required is a service interval indicator. The **engine check light** coming on will mean you have a fault.

You can simply re-set the Engine System Service Required by carrying out a simply re-set. Button A is located at the bottom and to the left of your speedo.
Ensure all doors are closed, Turn the ignition key to position 1(accessories), Press and hold button A, Immediately turn the ignition key to position 2 (ignition), Keep button A depressed until the service message has been re-set - a yellow 'info' light will illuminate, Release button A within 4 seconds - you will hear a beep when the re-set is complete. **This doesn't always work on the first try**. You may have to repeat the process various times.

Instead of an expensive Vadis system, there are many after-market tools available. Look up Torque Pro, or similar, on the net and see what you think of it. Together with your smart phone it is a very low cost way to see fault codes, etc,etc.

Comment: When I mentioned a generic OBD2 reader, I meant an ELM327 Bluetooth device and Torque/Carista. It didn't show anything, but seeing "DTC SET" on so many items makes me wonder/worried what's wrong with the car. Having read a few Volvo forums it seems you need the VADIS/VIDA to read them properly.

Comment: I have the same car. Those readings are normal :) @dsample

Comment: Having worked on Volvo I can understand your comments. Volvo diagnostics can be be a little esoteric.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't the "Engine System Service Required" message just mean it expects an oil change or other routine maintenance? Just as a maintenance reminder?

Comment: "TIME FOR REGULAR SERVICE" is the message for that

Answer (score -2):

This message means you have too much oil in the engine.  The dip stick should only read 3/4 from min to max.  This is on the D5 euro 4 engine (silver engine cover).

How do I know this..  I've had this issue on my V50 D5 a couple of weeks back when I thought it needed a top up.  Buy a syphon of Ebay £5 and suck some out.  Or go to a Volvo dealer and they will do it for £50 + they re set the messages.  Again I know this because I went to a Volvo dealer as no independant garage would suck oil out saying the level was correct, and thinking I was mad...

Comment: Tony - this is incorrect. That message is a generic one which could mean any number of things. In your case it may have been oil, but this is unlikely to answer the OP's question.