# I have a 2006 Volvo S60

Tags: volvo, s60, engine-system-service-required

My message board says engine system service required but no check engine light came on and I can't get a reading done unless the check engine light is on according to the shops and auto part stores please help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the car running any differently? If it's saying "engine system service required", it could be something as simple as needing an oil change. Not sure on that, but it's something to consider.

Comment: It literally just popped up when I started the car it runs fine in idle so far

Comment: I got an oil change on 5/31/2019 basically a month in a half ago the message that came up then was regular maintenance required

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/8032/4152). Check the answer by Allan to see if it doesn't shut that off for you. If so, let me know and I'll close out this question as a duplicate.

Comment: It did not work however Im up at Walmart and I had to get a few tools to tighten my battery connector and my starter solenoid cord bolt because that keeps coming loose so I did check the oil and it was low so I got some more oil and since I had to take the battery terminal off to tighten it it reset so we will see if it comes back on or if it was just the oil being low

Comment: The car died out on me in idle like once a week so I spoke to a shop he said that I should try the fuel system cleaner at jiffy lube and if that doesn't work to change the fuel filter I just bought this car like 3 months ago but he bought it from an auction so I'm gonna try that because who knows when the last time it was done and if that don't work I don't know

Comment: While it is good common maintenance to change out the fuel filter (in most cars), I wouldn't equate the car dieing at idle to be something I'd attribute to it. Don't be surprised if after the fuel filter is changed, it still does the same thing. A fuel filter usually shows itself as the engine cutting out at higher rpms because the fuel system cannot keep up with the engine demand. It's no problem at the lower engine speeds, unless the filter is completely plugged ... then it won't start in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same message in the past on my 2007 Volvo V50, and I'd imagine the meaning is the same. This message does unfortunately indicate a potential problem (as you mentioned, there's a different message for regular servicing).

Despite what the shops have said, there probably are fault codes to read. If you really can't persuade anyone to try and read them, you can buy scanners yourself for very little cost.

I found that a bluetooth based OBDII reader combined with the Torque mobile app worked well.